# No publish option in VS 2017 Pro for ASP.NET Core app

Tags: azure, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created a `asp.net core web application` with VS2017 version 15.3.5, but I have no option to `Publish to Azure`, normally you right-click on the project and get the `Publish` option.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Extensions and tools.

Make sure you  "Microsoft Azure App Service Tools" re-enabled "Microsoft Azure App Service Tools" is enabled.

If enabled disable and enable again.

Comment: I don't have  "Microsoft Azure App Service Tools" available, even when I search 'Azure' it doesn't come up

Comment: If you don't have it, Install it from https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/azure-tools/

Comment: If you search for Azure you can find it

Comment: COuldn't find it, is it perhaps called Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools now?